# change a clipper code to bypass authentication of a old program

Tags: authentication, dos, clipper

Hi a friend of mine asked me to recover a password of a program written in clipper back in 1994. I got myself a decompiler (Valkyrie 5) and decompiled the EXE-file. I located a procedure called USERLOGIN. The problem is that i dont know how to program in clipper. I would be very thankfull if someone could edit the procedure so it won't ask for authentication anymore.

```
#include "common.ch"
#include "inkey.ch"

********************************
Function USERLOGON

   Local Local1:= -1, Local2:= .F., Local3, Local4, Local5:= 3, ;
      Local6:= 3, Local7:= 7, Local8:= 41, Local9, Local10, Local11, ;
      Local12, Local13, Local14, Local15
   Local3:= 1
   Local9:= {}
   Local13:= setcursor()
   If (!netuse(diskname() + ":" + dirname() + "\" + "sinusr.dbf", ;
         "users"))
      Return Local1
   EndIf
   dbSetFilter({ || users->valid })
   Local14:= box(Local5, Local6, Local7, Local8, Nil, ;
      coltonum("GR+/B"))
   Do While (!Local2)
      Local10:= Space(12)
      Local11:= Space(10)
      setcursor(1)
      If (!Empty(n_shellver()))
         Local10:= padr(nnetwhoami(), 12)
      EndIf
      wininfo(Local14, @Local5, @Local6, @Local7, @Local8)
      @ Local5 + 1, Local6 + 5 Say "User............." Color "GR+/B"
      SetPos(Row(), Col() + 1)
      AAdd(Local9, __Get({ |_1| IIf(ISNIL(_1), Local10, Local10:= ;
         _1) }, "cUName", "@K!", Nil, Nil):display())
      @ Local5 + 2, Local6 + 5 Say "Password........." Color "GR+/B"
      SetPos(Row(), Col() + 1)
      AAdd(Local9, __Get({ |_1| IIf(ISNIL(_1), Local11, Local11:= ;
         _1) }, "cUPass", "@K!", Nil, Nil):display())
      Local9[2]:reader({ |_1| gt_grpassw(_1) })
      wreadmodal(Local9, 0)
      Local11:= Local9[2]:cargo()
      Local9:= {}
      If (LastKey() == K_ESC .OR. !winisinuse(Local14))
         If (winisinuse(Local14))
            winclose(Local14)
         EndIf
         Return Local1
      EndIf
      Local10:= alltrim(Local10)
      Local12:= {}
      Locate For Local10 == alltrim(users->emri)
      Do While (Found())
         AAdd(Local12, users->id)
         Continue
      EndDo
      For Local4:= 1 To Len(Local12)
         If ((Local15:= upass(Local12[Local4])) != Nil)
            If (alltrim(Local11) == Local15)
               Local2:= .T.
               Exit
            EndIf
         EndIf
      Next
   EndDo
   If (users->id != Local12[Local4])
      users->(dbGoTop())
      Locate For Local12[Local4] == users->id
      If (!Found())
         msg("Fatal error in user's file !", 3)
         Return -1
      EndIf
   EndIf
   For Local4:= 1 To MaxCol()
      winchgpos(0, 3)
   Next
   boxc(Local14)
   setcursor(Local13)
   If (users->in)
      tone(500, 10)
      Local4:= al_box("User " + Trim(users->emri) + ;
         " is already IN;" + "Do You Want to Jump In ?", 2, ;
         {" Yes ", " No  "}, 2, "WARNING")
      If (Local4 == 1)
         msg("More than One User with the same Name might cause Trouble !", ;
            3)
      Else
         Close
         Return -1
      EndIf
   ElseIf (netrlock())
      Replace users->in With .T.
      Unlock
      dbcommit()
   Else
      Close
      Return -1
   EndIf
   Static148[1]:= users->id
   Static148[2]:= alltrim(users->emri)
   Static148[3]:= alltrim(users->dirpriv)
   Static148[4]:= users->gjuha1
   Static148[5]:= users->gjuha2
   Static148[6]:= alltrim(users->emriiplote)
   Local1:= Static148[1]
   Close
   Return Local1

* EOF
```

Comment: I don't know clipper either, but the code `((Local15:= upass(Local12[Local4])) != Nil) ... If (alltrim(Local11) == Local15)` looks like it's retrieving then checking the user's password, so maybe you could try removing that conditional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially guesswork, but here's my interpretation:

Read the user's password from the console into `Local9[2]`:

```
@ Local5 + 2, Local6 + 5 Say "Password........." Color "GR+/B"
...
Local9[2]:reader({ |_1| gt_grpassw(_1) })
wreadmodal(Local9, 0)
```

Put the password into `Local11`:

```
Local11:= Local9[2]:cargo()
```

Fetch all user ids into `Local12` via `Local10`:

```
Locate For Local10 == alltrim(users->emri)
Do While (Found())
    AAdd(Local12, users->id)
    Continue
EndDo
```

Get each user's password into `Local15`, and if the password's present *and* matches the password in `Local11`, verify the user:

```
For Local4:= 1 To Len(Local12)
    If ((Local15:= upass(Local12[Local4])) != Nil)
        If (alltrim(Local11) == Local15)
            Local2:= .T.
            Exit
        EndIf
    EndIf
Next
```

**The fix**

Just remove the password check code. Not being certain about the purpose of all the rest of the code, I'd recommend leaving it alone. I've preserved the retrieval of the user's password, as maybe there's a good reason not to log in a user who has no password at all (perhaps that's how an account is disabled. The last block above could be changed to this:

```
For Local4:= 1 To Len(Local12)
    If ((Local15:= upass(Local12[Local4])) != Nil)
        Local2:= .T.
    EndIf
Next
```